# Tomcat is crashing after a web service call deployed on tomcat

Tags: macos, web-services, tomcat, memory-leaks, java-memory-leaks

Deployed a webservice on tomcat 7.0.99

Tomcat is running on MacOS, We are doing multiple web service calls to the service deployed on Tomcat. After completion of first service call the tomcat is crashing(even other services are in mid of processesing).

When I verified in catalina.out in the path /logs/, found below logs

Logs Snippet:

```
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8012"]
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/SampleTestWS] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/SampleTestWS] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/SampleTestWS] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/SampleTestWS] appears to have started a thread named [Exec Default Executor] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/SampleTestWS] appears to have started a thread named [Exec Stream Pumper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/SampleTestWS] appears to have started a thread named [Exec Stream Pumper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/SampleTestWS] appears to have started a thread named [OkHttp ConnectionPool] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/SampleTestWS] appears to have started a thread named [Okio Watchdog] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/SampleTestWS] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@531e8197]) and a value of type [io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver] (value [io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver, Capabilities: {app=/volumes/fileshare/InstallationFiles/Android/FoxFast.apk, appPackage=com.fox.foxfast.universal.integ, automationName=UIAutomator2, databaseEnabled=false, desired={platformName=android, app=/volumes/fileshare/InstallationFiles/Android/FoxFast.apk, automationName=UIAutomator2, deviceName=OnePlus GM1901, noReset=true, platformVersion=10, udid=e7f349bf}, deviceApiLevel=29, deviceManufacturer=OnePlus, deviceModel=GM1901, deviceName=e7f349bf, deviceScreenDensity=380, deviceScreenSize=1080x2340, deviceUDID=e7f349bf, javascriptEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=true, noReset=true, pixelRatio=2.375, platform=LINUX, platformName=Android, platformVersion=10, statBarHeight=80, takesScreenshot=true, udid=e7f349bf, viewportRect={left=0, top=80, width=1080, height=2066}, warnings={}, webStorageEnabled=false}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/SampleTestWS] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@4f56cd3c]) and a value of type [io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService] (value [io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService@53bd2ff]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8012"]
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
Feb 18, 2020 4:53:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8012"]
```

Could someone let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: This is not enough information.  You've got just the shutdown messages - you need to go further back in the log.  Don't worry too much about the other messages yet until you find out what it shutting down Tomcat.

Comment: @stdunbar, I did not find any other errors or exceptions other than element not found as the webservice deployed contains a selenium script which searches for a element when it is not found it will throws an exception